# how to change google chrome colors from a gtk theme

Tags: google-chrome, themes, gtk, tabs

I am currently using the dracula theme in gnome, but it has the problem that the active google chrome tab is the same color as the rest

There are other gtk themes that manage to change the title bar color, but I am not succeeding.

I have edited the theme and changed the selected_bg_color property, but I can't get the colors to change in chrome, I'm using ubuntu 18.04

I know that I could add a theme to google chrome, but unfortunately adding a theme loses the styling of the title bar buttons in gtk

Dracula theme:

[image]

Materia theme:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly, I achive change this, the stpes are the folowing (using dracula theme):

1. modify the .scss files in the gtk-3.20, for example create new file withthe folowing:

   .background.chromium {
   color: $fg_color;
   background-color: $base_color;
   }
2. compile theme, execute `gulp default` in the dracula theme folder
3. change the theme to refresh changes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change color of current tab:-
Open a New Tab in Chrome. On the right hand corner, click on `Customize Chrome`. Then go to `Color and Theme` and select the color you want. This way chrome shows the colors you selected. Not the color selected by gtk themes.

Comment: using custom colors and themes in chrome configuration loses the styling of the title bar buttons (close, minimize, maximize) in gtk :(